# How to escape JSON values with Single Quotes(apostrophe) within JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, single-quotes

When the data is passed (not mixed with any special characters) to the JavaScript function, then it would console the data. But when the data is passed with a single quote result's out an error in the console

1. **`"ask_game_name":"FIFA 17"` - It would print without any errors**
2. **`"ask_game_name":"Assassin's Creed IV"` - It would result as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" exactly pointing at the apostrophe**

Here is the below snippets of code followed while generating such an error in PHP

```
onclick='UserQueries(<?php echo json_encode($askInfoData); ?>)'
```

Data will be passed inside the JavaScript as an argument parameter and displays the JSON values

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function UserQueries(data)  
{
    console.log(data);
}

</script>
```

Here is what the Data consoled after passing it into JS.

```
UserQueries({"ask_info_id":"1","ask_user_id":"1","ask_game_name":"FIFA 17","username":"Nishanth","avatar":"1800766906.png"})

UserQueries({"ask_info_id":"2","ask_game_id":"3","ask_game_name":"Assassin
```

How should I need to display the values in the console containing single quotes values?

Comment: @RobG — No! ```\``` is not an HTML escape character.

Comment: @Quentin—oops, missed the context. `<li data-foo='{"ask_game_name":"Assassin&#39;s Creed IV"}'>` might be better. :-) But most seem to prefer double quotes for HTML attributes so there's more work to do…

Comment: @RobG — That's what `htmlspecialchars` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a string safe to insert into an HTML attribute:

- Use `htmlspecialchars`
- Use `"` to delimit the attribute value, or set the option on `htmlspecialchars` to include `'` in the escaped data.

Such:

```
onclick="UserQueries(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($askInfoData)); ?>)"
```

Comment: No. Tried result will be the same as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: @Nishanthॐ — What does the resulting `onclick` attribute look like?

Comment: I'm not getting what attributes you are saying. Could you brief it out

Comment: You have a PHP program. It generates some HTML. In that HTML is an onclick attribute. That.

Comment: <li> List Item tag

Comment: @Nishanthॐ — You haven't formatted that in such a way that it can be read

Comment: No. Tried out passing single parameter such as `onclick='load_query_msg(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($group_user->ask_game_name)); ?>)'` leading to runtime error and  `onclick='load_query_msg(<?php echo addcslashes($askInfoData->ask_game_name, "'")); ?>)' ` it is leading to syntax error

Comment: @Nishanthॐ — I said to use `"` to delimit the attribute value, but you continue to use `'`. You have to do *everything* said in the answer, not part of it.

Comment: @Nishanthॐ — Using `addcslashes` is nonsense. HTML doesn't use slashes as escape cahracters.